# piston-opengl_graphics: `can't find crate`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates, rust-piston

I am building a piston program, which I committed yesterday.
When running it unchanged today ( `cargo run` / `cargo check`), these are my error messages from the piston-opengl_graphics crate:

`can't find crate for x` for most of its dependancies; which seems to causes `unresolved import` or `failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate` as well.

This error first happened when trying `cargo build --release` (after many successful debug builds), but now occurs for any build / check.

I came back to the **exact** [Piston-Tutorials](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/Piston-Tutorials/tree/master/getting-started)' beginner guide, but the same errors occurred. The exact error message:

```plaintext
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `piston`
     --> C:\Users\win10\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\piston2d-opengl_graphics-0.82.0\src\back_end.rs:2:1
      |
    2 | extern crate piston;
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

I tried using a nightly rust version and changing piston-opengl_graphics version, in vain. (the latter gives me other errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the piston2d-opengl_graphics folder of the error message location.

This was probably caused by some Windows admin restriction, because I couldn't remove the full folder instantly, while I could with others. (so I removed all its content, then removed the folder itself).